# regEx + search capability in sfdc platform

Tags: soql, case, sosl, regular-expressions

Looking for suggestions on accomplishing search + regEx in sfdc, to search cases which have occurrence of the phrase 'PROVIDED BY:' in case history and get the case number where this phrase was found plus whatever followed this phrase in search results, so:

If case 123456 had 'PROVIDED BY: Jay Leno' somewhere in the case history I'm looking to extract:

case 123456 and Jay Leno

I understand that this might involve multiple steps like:

1. First search and build a list of cases where the comments contain
   'PROVIDED BY:' and get the whole comment blob.
   ("case": "case #", "comment" : "... PROVIDED BY: ...")
2. Then do regEx extraction on the "comment" portion to pull out the names at the end of 'PROVIDED BY:'.

If this is a common workflow in sfdc mining do throw in key terms I should be searching.

Comment: That should be the way. For this you should make use of Patter and Matcher objects to create the regex in Apex.